# How to smoothen data in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, smoothing

I am trying to smoothen a scatter plot shown below using SciPy's B-spline representation of 1-D curve. The data is available [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwwhEMUIYGyTaUZ3bThoNXc2UW8/view?usp=sharing).

[image]

The code I used is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate

data = np.genfromtxt("spline_data.dat", delimiter = '\t')
x = 1000 / data[:, 0]
y = data[:, 1]
x_int = np.linspace(x[0], x[-1], 100)
tck = interpolate.splrep(x, y, k = 3, s = 1)
y_int = interpolate.splev(x_int, tck, der = 0)

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (5.15,5.15))
plt.subplot(111)
plt.plot(x, y, marker = 'o', linestyle='')
plt.plot(x_int, y_int, linestyle = '-', linewidth = 0.75, color='k')
plt.xlabel("X")
plt.ylabel("Y")
plt.show()
```

I tried changing the order of the spline and the smoothing condition, but I am not getting a smooth plot.

***B-spline interpolation should be able to smoothen the data but what is wrong? Any alternate method to smoothen this data?***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a larger smoothing parameter. For example, `s=1000`:

```
tck = interpolate.splrep(x, y, k=3, s=1000)
```

This produces:

[image: interpolation]

Answer (score 4):

Assuming we are dealing with noisy observations of some phenomena, Gaussian Process Regression might also be a good choice. Knowledge about the variance of the noise can be included into the parameters (nugget) and other parameters can be found using Maximum Likelihood estimation. Here's a simple example of how it could be applied:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcess

data = np.genfromtxt("spline_data.dat", delimiter='\t')
x = 1000 / data[:, 0]
y = data[:, 1]
x_pred = np.linspace(x[0], x[-1], 100)

# <GP regression>
gp = GaussianProcess(theta0=1, thetaL=0.00001, thetaU=1000, nugget=0.000001)
gp.fit(np.atleast_2d(x).T, y)
y_pred = gp.predict(np.atleast_2d(x_pred).T)
# </GP regression>

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5.15, 5.15))
plt.subplot(111)
plt.plot(x, y, marker='o', linestyle='')
plt.plot(x_pred, y_pred, linestyle='-', linewidth=0.75, color='k')
plt.xlabel("X")
plt.ylabel("Y")
plt.show()
```

which will give:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your specific case, you could also try changing the last argument of the np.linspace function to a smaller number, `np.linspace(x[0], x[-1], 10)`, for example.

Demo code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate

data = np.random.rand(100,2)
tempx = list(data[:, 0])
tempy = list(data[:, 1])
x = np.array(sorted([point*10 + tempx.index(point) for point in tempx]))
y = np.array([point*10 + tempy.index(point) for point in tempy])
x_int = np.linspace(x[0], x[-1], 10)
tck = interpolate.splrep(x, y, k = 3, s = 1)
y_int = interpolate.splev(x_int, tck, der = 0)

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (5.15,5.15))
plt.subplot(111)
plt.plot(x, y, marker = 'o', linestyle='')
plt.plot(x_int, y_int, linestyle = '-', linewidth = 0.75, color='k')
plt.xlabel("X")
plt.ylabel("Y")
plt.show()
```

You could also smooth the data with a rolling_mean in pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [...(your data here)...]

smoothendData = pd.rolling_mean(data,5)
```

the second argument of rolling_mean is the moving average (rolling mean) period.  You can also reverse the data 'data.reverse', take a rolling_mean of the data that way, and combine it with the forward rolling mean.  Another option is exponentially weighted moving averages:
[Pandas: Exponential smoothing function for column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16762014/pandas-exponential-smoothing-function-for-column)

or using bandpass filters:
[fft bandpass filter in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19122157/fft-bandpass-filter-in-python)
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/signal.html