# Detect when the jumps occur in Python

Tags: python, dataframe

I am attempting to smooth out some data as per the visualization below:[image: Data visualization]

I've reduce the noise using code below, but I'm having difficulties understanding how I can recognise when these jumps are occurring, and smoothing the transition between them:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.signal import savgol_filter


df = pd.read_csv('e:/Projects/HiringTest/submission/sample.txt', sep = ' ')

# Data befrore filtering.
df.plot(x ='x', y='y', linewidth=0.2)

# Savitzky-Golay filter implementation
dataIIR = df
dataIIR['y'] = savgol_filter(df['y'], 101, 2)
dataIIR.plot(x ='x', y='y', linewidth=0.4)
   
plt.show()
```

My initial thoughts are to take the difference between points N and N+1, find where it is greater than some fixed value, and implement some sort of algorithm between, say, N-10 and N+10 that applies a scaling value to the data to smooth the steps - being new to Python, however, I do know how to put such a thing into practice. If anyone has any suggestions on a way to do the following it would be much appreciated:

- Detect when the jumps occur.
- Smooth the transition between jumps.

Comment: not exactly a duplicate, but it might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16762014/pandas-exponential-smoothing-function-for-column ... google "site:stackoverflow.com pandas smoothing"

Comment: just loop through the indices and values of the xy and record the indices where the jump occurs using the threshold method you described